# MySQL query from multiple tables with an array (PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I’m trying to implement a logging system to my site. I can easily log information into table “LOGS” but I’d like to present this to the users in more “human readable” form.

Table LOGS has columns like `log_id, user_id, customer_id, event_id, timestamp` etc. User_id refers to table users and I’d like to user “username” from there. Customer_id refers to table customers and I’d like to use “customername” column value from there. Event_id refers to events table and I’d like use “description” column value from there. You get the idea.

What I’d like to print to my web page is something like this:

```
User John edited customer Wal Mart at 12:25pm
User John viewed customer Burger King at 12:30pm
```

….
User John deleted customer Costco at 12:40pm

So I’d like to query 20 rows from “LOGS” and use corresponding values from other tables and present it to the users. I can do basic queries but this is a little bit over my head because I’m just learning…

Thanks for your answers.

edit: Sorry about the poor layout :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are following the best method for learning : practice, search, ... Congratulations.

Your requirment can be achieved with tables `JOIN`. Example:

```
SELECT u.username, c.customername, e.description, l.timestamp
FROM   logs AS l #Using aliases to avoid long names
JOIN   users AS u ON l.user_id = u.id #The JOIN condition : basically, foreign 
                                      #key equal to foreign table primary key
JOIN   customers AS c ON l.customer_id = c.id
JOIN   events AS e ON l.event_id = e.id
#YOUR ORDER Clause
LIMIT 20
```

Please note that if any of the foreign keys field is optional (can be NULL), you should use `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` families. In that case, "foreign fields" will have NULL values.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is basic SQL concepts and syntax.

Have a look at the employee name & salary on this MySql Manual page:
[JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
select
  log_id, 
  customer_name, 
  user_name
from
  logs
  inner join customers on customers.customer_id = logs.customer_id
  inner join users on users.user_id = logs.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a join sql command:

```
SELECT a.*, b.username,c.customername,d.description
FROM logs a
INNER JOIN customers b
ON a.user_id=b.username
INNER JOIN events c
ON a.event_id=c.customerID
WHERE a.user_id = '$userID'
```

Something like this. But for the full query i need more info on what you want to get and what your tables look like.

Comment: JOIN clause comes before WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `JOIN` the two tables. Here's an example:

```
SELECT 
    `logs`.*, 
    `users`.`username`, 
    `events`.`description`, 
    `customers`.`customername` 
FROM 
    `logs`
JOIN 
    `users` 
    ON `users`.`id` = `logs`.`user_id`
JOIN 
    `events` 
    ON `events`.`id` = `logs`.`event_id`
JOIN 
    `customers` 
    ON `customers`.`id` = `logs`.`customer_id`
LIMIT 10
```

This will join `logs`, `users`, `events` and `customers` and fetch 10 results. You can also add an `ORDER BY` if you want to order by a timestamp or something else.

---

I tend to use backtick `` ` `` around column and table names to avoid issues with reserved words. I find this to be a good convention to hold myself against. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Thanks, it's easy when you know what you are doing.

Comment: @JouniLahtinen And if you don't know it, it's easy to become more clever on Stack Overflow :-) Please remember to accept an answer.